# rails 3.1, simple_form, using haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, simple-form

How would I write this simple_form in haml:

```
<%= simple_form_for (@quiz) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="inputs">
    <%= f.input :body %>
    <%= f.fields_for :quiz_choices do |builder| %>
         <%= render "quiz_choice_fields", :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
    <p><%= link_to_add_association  "Add a choice",f, :quiz_choices %></p>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my try:

```
- simple_form_for (@quiz) do |f|
- f.error_notification
  .inputs
    = f.input :body
    - f.fields_for :quiz_choices do |builder|
    = render "quiz_choice_fields", :f => builder

    %p= link_to_add_association  "Add a choice",f, :quiz_choices
  .actions
    = f.button :submit
```

Here is the error:

Extracted source (around line #12):

```
9:   .actions
10:     = f.button :submit
```

Comment: ANY time you need to convert erb to haml, try: http://html2haml.heroku.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well any time you have `<%=`, it should become `=` in haml, not `-`. Also, for a loop or block, you need to indent the code under it.

```
- simple_form_for (@quiz) do |f|
- f.error_notification
  .inputs
    = f.input :body
    - f.fields_for :quiz_choices do |builder|
    = render "quiz_choice_fields", :f => builder

    %p= link_to_add_association  "Add a choice",f, :quiz_choices
  .actions
    = f.button :submit
```

Should become:

```
= simple_form_for (@quiz) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .inputs
    = f.input :body
    = f.fields_for :quiz_choices do |builder|
      = render "quiz_choice_fields", :f => builder
    %p= link_to_add_association  "Add a choice",f, :quiz_choices
  .actions
    = f.button :submit
```

Comment: thanks, I have another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005831/rails-3-1-partial-using-haml I will appreciate your help!