# rails 3.1, partial, using haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I am trying to use haml in a partial, I wrote:

```
%p.nested-check-fields
    = f.input :is_correct
    = link_to_remove_fields "remove choice", f
```

but, in the resulted HTML, I get

```
<p class="nested-check-fields"> </p>
<div class="input boolean optional">
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="quiz[quiz_choices_attributes][1320389712363][is_correct]">
<input id="quiz_quiz_choices_attributes_1320389712363_is_correct" class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="quiz[quiz_choices_attributes][1320389712363][is_correct]">
<label class="boolean optional" for="quiz_quiz_choices_attributes_1320389712363_is_correct"> Is correct</label>
</div>
```

The question is, why the `<p class="nested-check-fields"> </p>` is empty ?? I was expecting to wrap the div inside it, what's wrong ??

Comment: isn't the convention: two spaces for indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haml is very strict about indentation (from the [documentation](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/)):

> Haml’s indentation can be made up of one or more tabs or spaces.
>   However, indentation must be consistent within a given document. Hard
>   tabs and spaces can’t be mixed, and the same number of tabs or spaces
>   must be used throughout.

It sounds like you can actually use 4 spaces instead of 2, but that means you have to use 4 spaces everywhere (you can't mix it). I'd recommend just sticking with 2-space indentation, as that's the most common.